# html onfocus browser issue

Tags: html, browser, onfocus

I am trying to clear out the text area on focus. This is the code i have used -
`<textarea type="text" name="Title" id="title" value="Title" onfocus="if
(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';" cols="20" rows="10" style="width:465px;color:grey;font-size:15px;" wrap="hard">Title</textarea>` 
This works perfectly in Mozilla Firefox but not in Opera. Can anyone tell me why is it so?

Comment: Your code snippet works fine for me in Opera 11. I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mkJHg/) for easier testing.

Comment: I am using the same browser(Opera 11.01) and yet the default value does not clear-off on focus. I have no idea why it is so. As I said, I have also tested it in Firefox 3.5.9 and it works fine.

Comment: So it seems like the problem is somewhere else in your page, the code you posted is absolutely correct. You could still try using HTML 5 `placeholder` and a Javascript plugin for browsers that do not support it.

Comment: Ok. I shall do that. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code and opened it with Opera 11.01 and it worked.

You can also try a JQuery Plugin : http://plugins.jquery.com/project/placeholder
or use HTML 5 Forms with Attribute `placeholder="Title"`.

Comment: I am using the same browser(Opera 11.01) and yet the default value does not clear-off on focus. I have no idea why it is so. As I said, I have also tested it in Firefox 3.5.9 and it works fine.